# Evaluate $\iint_R 15x +10y\ dA$ using a transformation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, linear-transformations

Evaluate
 $$\iint_R 15x + 10y\ dA$$
where R is the region is a parallelogram with vertices $(-1,4)$, $(1, -4)$, $(4, -1)$, and $(2, 7)$ ; 
$x = (u+v)/5$ and $y = (v-4u)/5$

I attempted this and got $$\iint_S5v-5u\ dvdu$$

with $-5\le v\le5$ and $0\le u\le 15$ and got the answer 5625.

According to webassign, the website where we're supposed to put our answer, I'm wrong. I was wondering where I went wrong, and if anyone could help. I'm assuming it was my limits.

Many thanks, Alex.

Comment: Just realised I didn't include the Jacobian. I have now got the correct result of 1125.

Comment: If you want, you can write an answer containing your corrected solution.